# How would society change if people did not die from old age?

Tags: society, magic, culture, immortality

The latest generation of humans mutated a gene that keeps them from aging. They can still be killed by injury, disease, and malnutrition. But the they don't grow old like we do. If this was the case how would US change because of it? (specifically what new laws and organization would the government have to form because of this change)

This takes place in our world or at least the world identical to it.

Comment: Bryan this is way way to broad

Comment: I agree with James, this is a textbook example of a too broad question.

Comment: At what age does the ageing stop?

Comment: @James how exactly can I make this less broad?

Comment: @Roux they never start ageing

Comment: @BryanMcClure Then we will soon have a planet full of babies. Somehow I get the impression this is not what you want ;)

Comment: In any case the answer is simple; overpopulation increses starvation and famine, keeping the population in line.

Comment: @BryanMcClure You could define your society/culture for starters, there are many many many of them on planet Earth.  You need to explain how your "not aging" system works, mainly, how old do people appear/get to when they stop aging, cause agreed...a planet full of babies would be a problem...and finally you could narrow your scope regarding impact by selecting a particular aspect of society/culture.

Comment: @James I'm sorry I thought it was implied that I was talking about our society

Comment: First thing that comes to my mind is the Fairy Oddparents. Before you laugh, I'm mainly thinking about the importance of children in the fairy's world. It's a rare occasion and they're extremely important and regulated to prevent over-population.

Comment: @BryanMcClure "Our" is still really general and I have no way of knowing what *your* culture is as I don't know where you live or who you are.  Even within the US (I am guessing since it is not in your profile) there are many different cultures, some based on race, others on religion, others on geography...how these cultures react will vary between them.

Comment: @James of see your point.

Comment: @James is this better?

Comment: Better (and I promise I am not just trying to be difficult)  but I would still tailor it down a bit.  Just think of the difference between a millennial in San Francisco and a kid growing up in an Amish village in Pennsylvania.  Beyond that I would also consider breaking the pieces of culture into a series of questions.  You could have questions on education, politics, art, literature, the military, social media, music...etc etc etc.  Culture is a really *really* big topic...

Comment: @James ok is this better?

Comment: ok, they dont grow old, but how old they get? Its the same for male and females (think having kids as reason for this). If they stay healthy, could they just go on forever? Think overpopulation, think food, think life enjoyment, think work/retirement, unemployment, psychological factors, accumulating money and goods etc etc... Each little aspect of your question can have a very long discussion, its very very broad

Comment: @ErikvanDoren  AS I have already explained they mature but don't age.  So yes the woman are perfectly capable of have children

Comment: @BryanMcClure, the aging process starts right away: a body develops then progressively changes and declines, as every living thing does in their own lifespan. Saying that they mature but dont age explains little: is it a world full of teens? people in their 30s? 50s? 70s? As that situation is pure fantasy, its needed a frame of reference that tells exactly the condition of that body. A woman that will never enter menopause means A LOT of kids, just supporting that situation could make a question on its own. Just that one detail changes quite a bit in an answer, go figure all the rest.

Comment: @Erik vanDoren You seem to have mistaken maturing for aging. Let me try to fix that. Your body continuously replaces your whoren out cells with fresh new ones.  as you grow older your body dose this less efficiently.  This is called aging.

Comment: @ErikvanDoren   Maturing is when your body  in addition to creating new to replace you old ones is also make extra to fully develop your body.  You stop maturing when you body is fully complete that is to say it doesn't need to grow any more or add any thing new.  Obvious a teenager is not fully developed .

Comment: @ErikvanDoren   If I have confused you let me make it simple. The average human finish developing around age 25 .

Comment: @BryanMcClure, I'm a medical practitioner from quite some time. If you think your body ends "maturing" (as you call it) around 25 you are mistaken, things continuously are renewed, built up, adapted, if the process stop you hit decay. Take a bone, it will reach its "genetic blueprint" length but it doesnt mean its done developing, it keeps building up (or being demolished) in response to stimuli and body necessities. In your created world do what you want but in ours stages of life are many and each of them can change the view on what would happen in a world were everyone is at the same stage.

Comment: @ErikvanDoren I mean that the human body is completely developed at 25. Obviously it keeps been rebuild cells after that, how be it at a slower and slower rate.

Comment: @BryanMcClure, " the human body is completely developed at 25" No its not...

Answer (score 4):

While this question is way too broad, it reminded me of the movie [Time Out (2011)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1637688/) about a dystopian society where everyone was given eternal life, but everything would cost "time". Everyone would have to work and earn time, having their "time left" / "bank account" on their arm. The more time you have, the richer you are. Once you have 0 seconds left, you die (sick device, if you ask me).

I guess you could have a good picture of how eternal life could be adapted to avoid overpopulation, keeping the capitalism system, wealth gap and such...

Comment: Even in theory it only works if the government guarantees accommodation in a suitable area (near work/family/etc) for every person.

Comment: well it's a very touchy system anyway. I don't think people, at the start of the "all society stays young" revolution, would accept being eternal but still poor. My wild guess would be that only the rich people would be interested to join the "program" with these accommodations, but as every capitalistic/oligarchic economic system, the least rich people would have become poor (in time), and lose all of their advantages, which could lead to a situation like in the movie.

Comment: It doesn't work mathematically either, because it is a system where you can't have debts, and the whole economical system works only because of debts.

Comment: @AnneAunyme oh well i'm not the writer of the movie (book?), so i haven't developed much the economical possibilities, but I suppose there can still be a debt system, but without being in a "negative time" (like 500€ debt is -500€ in bank account). Let's suppose i want to buy a house which is 1year€ ("money time", using € because _dollar_ break the comment), but i only have 1week€, i'll just make a loan of 1year€, pay the house, and live with a 1year€ debt i'll have to pay. Classic loan system I suppose.

Comment: The problem is that the money disappears progressively, and no more money is produced. In fatally ends with everyone in debt or dead.